# Catalina Performance on MacBook Pro 16"

Tags: macos, mac, performance, macbook-pro, macos-catalina

I cannot believe how relatively slow my new MBP 16" is! I'm unable to understand what's causing this, I can't find anything in the logs or Activity Monitor that's providing any tips. I mean, even swiping with the mouse to the left or right causes a jittery fullscreen switch!

Here's the hardware information:

```
  Model Name:   MacBook Pro
  Model Identifier: MacBookPro16,1
  Processor Name:   8-Core Intel Core i9
  Processor Speed:  2,3 GHz
  Number of Processors: 1
  Total Number of Cores:    8
  L2 Cache (per Core):  256 KB
  L3 Cache: 16 MB
  Hyper-Threading Technology:   Enabled
  Memory:   32 GB
  Boot ROM Version: 1037.60.58.0.0 (iBridge: 17.16.12551.0.0,0)
```

Any idea where can I start looking or what kind of diagnostics I should do?

Thank you,
Sammy

Comment: And how relatively slow is it, exactly? What are you expecting, what are you seeing?

Comment: I must admit it's just down to my perception of graphic (visual) response. I'm under constant impression that my previous MacBook Pro 15" was faster. I don't know if there are any tools I can run to share numbers in a more objective manner?

Comment: Basic troubleshooting would mean starting in Safe Mode (if its OK then something you installed is messed up) Create a new user profile and see if that is better. You could aslo back it up, wipe it and start from a clean HD. If it is STILL slow after that (with nothing else installed) take it back to Apple and show them what is going on.